# Crystal report 10 Error : Failed to open a rowset

Tags: .net, sql, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports 10, running on SQL Server 2008 R2. The backend is in the server. When I run a report, it is working fine with my Admin userid and password but if I login with the client userid and password, I get the

[image: Error Message]

Error Message :Failed to open a rowset. 42000:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]

It sound like "Access Violation or syntax error".How to run the report in the client PC ?

Comment: Duplicate question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400717/crystal-reports-failed-to-open-a-rowset

Comment: It is not dulicate question.I am already refer it but it is not help me because i am using 'View' and it is working fine in 'Admin' login so the 'View' is present in the database.My question is "why it is not working in client pc ?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My System Administartor solve by problem by Right click my Username in the server --> Properties --> Server Roles --> select the option 'sysadmin' (already 'public' selected).Then i create a DNS, now the report is working in client machine also.